# C Printf takes %p as system()

Tags: c, pointers

I see that in a heap-based overflow tutorial:

```
printf("System: %p", system);
```

What is that address and what does it mean? Printed value remains same everytime i run.
Here it is all program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERROR -1
#define BUFSIZE 64

int goodfunc(const char *str); /* funcptr starts out as this */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   static char buf[BUFSIZE];
   static int (*funcptr)(const char *str);

   if (argc <= 2)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <buf> <goodfunc arg>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(ERROR);
   }

   printf("(for 1st exploit) system() = %p\n", system);
   printf("(for 2nd exploit, stack method) argv[2] = %p\n", argv[2]);
   printf("(for 2nd exploit, heap offset method) buf = %p\n\n", buf);

   funcptr = (int (*)(const char *str))goodfunc;
   printf("before overflow: funcptr points to %p\n", funcptr);

   memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
   strncpy(buf, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
   printf("after overflow: funcptr points to %p\n", funcptr);

   (void)(*funcptr)(argv[2]);
   return 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

/* This is what funcptr would point to if we didn't overflow it */
int goodfunc(const char *str)
{
   printf("\nHi, I'm a good function.  I was passed: %s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

---

As i understand somehow we point and pass argument "bash" to system() .

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not depended to runtime." ? Do you get the same result every time ? Do you get a different result every time ? Is `system` a variable you have, or is it the system() function from `stdlib.h`?

Comment: Yeah i get same result. Link to tutorial: http://www.cgsecurity.org/exploit/heaptut.txt

Comment: Any chance you can explain the (extremely unclear) statement "I try lots of times and see that it is not depended to runtime"?

Comment: `system` is a function. It's declared in `stdlib.h`. You've probably heard of it. Aside from the fact that `%p` isn't guaranteed to handle function pointers, there's nothing really tricky about this code. It just shows you where the `system` function has been loaded in your process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man system`:

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed. During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.

So, use `system()` to execute arbitrary code.

`%p` prints the value passed as a memory address.

The idea is you want to use this knowledge to make a vulnerable program execute `system("NotAVirus.exe")` through some kind of memory overrun.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`system` is a function from stdlib](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system), the code has undefined behavior, because `%p` requires a `void*` pointer. This code is passing a pointer to function instead, which is not compatible with a `void*` pointer.

You cannot fix this program by inserting a cast, i.e.

```
printf("System: %p", (void*)system);
```

because it is not allowed by the ISO C standard<sup>*</sup>.

Since the behavior is undefined, the statement could print whatever it wants, crash, or do anything else. However, the most likely behavior is that some number which represents the address of `system` gets re-interpreted as `void*` pointer, resulting in the behavior that you observe, i.e. the same number being printed.

<sup>*</sup> The only conversion allowed by C99 for pointers to functions is a conversion to other pointers to functions, as described in section 6.3.2.3.8. According to section J.5.7.2, converting function pointers to `void*` pointers is a common extension to the language, intended for use in debuggers.

Comment: Such a cast is not illegal per se. E.g. POSIX requires that function pointers can be converted to `void *` and back.

Comment: @melpomene [ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type](http://ideone.com/Kjy29q).

Comment: So? Just because a compiler says so doesn't make it true (also, that's not an error by default; you used `-Werror=pedantic`).

Comment: @melpomene ISO C = standard

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, I know? What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: @melpomene It's not "a compiler says", it's "standard says". You can convert a function pointer only to other function pointers. Conversion to `void*` pointer is a *common extension* (see C99, section J.5.7.2), but it does not mean it's allowed everywhere.

Comment: Not "Just because a compiler says ...", the standard says so

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your link goes to compiler output, not the standard. So yes, it's "compiler says".

Comment: @AlterMann Where does the standard say so?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, I know? What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Why do you think type casts change addresses?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You claimed *It's not "a compiler says", it's "standard says"*. That's unsupported (and a non-sequitur because you hadn't referenced the standard before).

Comment: @melpomene Did you not know about the standard before I mentioned the section where the conversion is specifically documented as a common extension?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: IMHO that error message "ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type" is incorrect. There is no constraint that forbids such a conversion; see N1570 6.5.4, "Cast operators", which forbids conversions between pointers and floating-point types. 6.3.2.3, which covers pointer conversions, doesn't specify the behavior of such a conversion, which merely means that the behavior is undefined. Is there a constraint that I've missed?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What you cited isn't technically part of the standard (the appendices aren't normative). You haven't provided evidence that the cast is actually illegal.

Comment: @KeithThompson While we're at it, haven't we already reached undefined territory at `#include <unistd.h>`?

Comment: @melpomene: The behavior of `#include <unistd.h>` is not defined by the standard -- but it is defined by POSIX. It's not the nasal-demon kind of UB unless you use it in a non-POSIX environment.

Comment: @KeithThompson If we can assume POSIX, then converting function pointers to void pointers is also well defined AFAIK.

Comment: @melpomene: I'm not sure that's correct. IIRC, POSIX says that a `void*` returned by `dlsym()` can be meaningfully converted to a function pointer (if the symbol refers to a function), but it no longer guarantees such conversions in general. (They're likely to work on most systems, though.) In any case, `printf("%p", system)` definitely has undefined behavior; `printf("%p", (void*)system)` is safer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Hmm, I don't see that in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html.

Comment: @KeithThompson My interpretation of the list of allowed conversions from 6.3.2.3 is that the list is complete, and that whatever's not on the list is UB. I do not see a statement that would say anything about conversions not on the list, so perhaps my interpretation is too strict (the only conversion which is explicitly allowed for pointers to functions is to other pointer to function, i.e. 6.3.2.3.8). It makes sense for `fptr-to-void*` conversion to be undefined, because keeping functions in an entirely separate memory space is not that uncommon.

Comment: @melpomene: "The return value from `dlsym()`, cast to a pointer to the type of the named symbol, can be used to call (in the case of a function) or access the contents of (in the case of a data object) the named symbol."

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I agree. Note that anything not on the list has undefined behavior; it's not, as gcc incorrectly claims, "forbidden" (which would imply a violation of a syntax rule or constraint). See also N1570 4p2; undefined behavior includes behavior for which the standard provides no definition, not just behavior that is explicitly undefined.